# CSS3 width and heigh percentage of his container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I need to do something similar to the question

[Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

I have a bootstrap grid of two cells that on mobile goes on a single row each

I would like to insert a box with a fixed proportion of 4:3 and I can't use viewport width and height proportion since the content is already inside bootstrap cell

I would like to know if in CSS3 is possible to express width and height of an element based on his parent width

```css
#box-01,
#box-02 {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 15vw;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="box-01">4:3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div id="box-02">4:3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I would like to know if in CSS3 is possible to express width and height of an element based on his parent width` . No, i don't think it's possible with just CSS

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have one possibility.

**Note:** Consider this a hack which probably should not be used in production code.

Percentage values of the `margin` and `padding` properties are relative to the *width* of the containing block. This means `margin-top` and `padding-top` (running along the Y axis) will respond to changes made to the width of the parent (running along the X axis).

In the following example, `.child` has a width of `50%`, which is relative to the width of the parent. To have its *height* respond to the *width* of the parent, we can simulate a height using the `padding-top` property. Now both the width and the simuated height of `.child` are relative to the width of `.parent`, thus preserving the aspect ratio.

(Try resizing `.parent` to see how `.child` responds while keeping the aspect ratio.)

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.child {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(50% * 0.75);
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now, as anyone will quickly find out, this does not allow for any contents inside `.child`. To fix this, you can introduce another nested `<div>` named `.grand-child`. Make `.child` relatively positioned and `.grand-child` absolutely positioned inside of `.child`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: orange;
  overflow: scroll;
  resize: both;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(50% * 0.75);
  background: yellow;
}
.grand-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="grand-child">
            Hello world
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```